# Proof of a left R-module M is free with basis X iff M is internal direct summand of Rx where x is in X

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

I have a confusion in the proof. 
Let $M$ is internal direct sum of $Rx$ where $x$ is in $X$.
I have no trouble in proving that $X$ generates $M$.
Now when we show that $X$ is linearly independent.we take distinct elements $y_1,y_2,...y_n$ in $X$ such that $r_1y_1+r_2y_2+...r_ny_n=0$ where $r_i$ is in $R$ for each $i$ from 1 to $n$.
Now we say that since $M$ is internal direct sum of $Rx$ where $x$ is in $X$ therefore 0 has a unique representation and hence each $r_i=0$. This is exactly the step I didn't understand, since 0 has unique representation, then I think it should have been said that each $r_iy_i=0$.
So please explain why is it $r_i=0$ instead of $r_iy_i=0$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I think the question is lacking some details and wrong in the generality ($R$ ring, $M$ left module). Consider $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ as $\Bbb Z$ module. As $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is cyclic we have $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z = \Bbb Z \cdot [1]$ meaning the submodule generated by $[1]$. As such it is an internal direct sum. Meanwhile, out of cardinality reasons $\Bbb Z^{\oplus n} \not\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ for any $n$. I think what might be missing is that $\operatorname{Ann}(x_i) = 0$ for each $x_i$ in $X$.